# cannot convert int to string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

Hi the problem in the code is at the end finalResult[index]= mark; code, mark gives error. It says cannot convert int to string. How can i fix it ?

```
    System.out.println("Please choose a criteria (2-7) ?");
    topic = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a mark :");
    int mark = in.nextInt();
    final int size = cols.length;
    String[] finalResult = new String[size];
    int index = 0;

    while(index<finalResult.length ) {
        if (index==topic) {
          finalResult[index]= mark;
        } else {
        finalResult[index]=cols[index];
        }
        index++; 

    }
    }
```

Comment: try something like `finalResult[index]= mark + "";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
finalResult[index] = mark;
```

You can't put ***int number*** to ***String array***:

> Error:
>   incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

You need to convert number to **String** before adding to the **array**.

You have to change as follows:

```
finalResult[index] = String.valueOf(mark);
```

or

```
finalResult[index] = mark + "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting integer to string is done with method `String.valueOf` so in your case it would be

```
String.valueOf(mark)
```

Comment: Index is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mark declaration in the code as below,

```
String mark = in.nextLine();
```